# Particular solution of a 2nd order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Having the euation $x''-a^2x=e^{bt}$, $a>0, b\in \mathbb R$ I have found that $x_h(t)=c_1e^{at}+c_2e^{-at}$, but I don't know how to find its particular solution. Cand somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: Try $x_p(t) = A t$.

Comment: Try  then $y=At$ Are you sure it's $e^b$ and not $e^{bt}$ ?

Comment: $e^{bt}$ I have modified

Comment: But is there a more general way to find $Xp$s?

Comment: The variation of constants (or parameters) is another method to solve linear differential equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x''-a^2x=e^{bt}$$
For $b \ne \pm a$  try:
$$y_p=Ae^{bt}$$
For $b= \pm a$  then you have to try:
$$y_p=tAe^{bt}$$

For solving the DE with variation of constants method. Plug $y_p$ in the DE and find the constant $A$.